# Why do arrow keys behave differently in insert mode than in other modes?

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode, movement

### Background

I would like to disable arrow keys in all modes. This is what I tried:

```
"EDIT: added remap for <esc> as per the comments
inoremap <esc> <nop>

inoremap <up> <nop>
inoremap <down> <nop>
inoremap <left> <nop>
inoremap <right> <nop>
"inoremap <ESC>oA <nop>
"inoremap <ESC>oB <nop>
"inoremap <ESC>oC <nop>
"inoremap <ESC>oD <nop>
nnoremap <up> <nop>
nnoremap <down> <nop>
nnoremap <left> <nop>
nnoremap <right> <nop>
vnoremap <up> <nop>
vnoremap <down> <nop>
vnoremap <left> <nop>
vnoremap <right> <nop>
```

This works fine for normal and visual modes, but in insert mode it starts writing funny characters if I press the arrow keys, like `OCOCOCOCOCODODODODODOAOAOAOBOB`.

### Question

What is the reason that the arrow keys behave differently in insert mode than normal/visual modes? (Or do they actually behave the same, and `OCOAOB` has no effect in normal/visual modes?)

**Update**: It turned out that the cause for the behaviour was the remapping of the `esc` key (thanks to @filbranden for [pointing that out](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/23134/why-do-arrow-keys-behave-differently-in-insert-mode-than-in-other-modes#comment42002_23134)!)
However, the question is still open: why do the remapped arrow keys in *insert* mode behave differently, if the `esc` key is also remapped?

### Remarks

- I am running Ubuntu and using Vim in a *local* terminal (i.e. not ssh'ing somewhere remotely)
- I already found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23558540/3398271), and tried to change all kinds of terminal settings/nocompatible mode. The only difference I could achieve was this: `[C[C[C[C[D[D[D[D[D[C[C[A[B[D[C`. (**EDIT**: this is caused e.g. by `:set term=ansi`)
- The issue is reproducible also with a minimal `.vimrc` containing only the lines above (i.e., it is not due to a plugin interferring).
- By uncommenting the commented lines, the problem is fixed, but 1. I would really like to understand what is going on; 2. that solution feels a bit hacky to me, although it works.

### Answer to comments

```
:set term? t_ku?


term=screen-256color
t_ku <Up>        ^[OA
```

Platform, OS: Ubuntu 19.04 on x86_64, terminal vim

Pressing arrows in terminal:

```
$ cat
^[[A^[[B^[[A^[[C^[[D^[[C^[[B^[[A
```

```
vim -u NONE -N
```

--> problem is not reproducible

Contents of `/etc/vim/vimrc` (comments removed):

```
runtime! debian.vim

if has("syntax")
  syntax on
endif

if filereadable("/etc/vim/vimrc.local")
  source /etc/vim/vimrc.local
endif
```

Comment: What does this command tell you in Vim? `:set term? t_ku?`

Comment: @filbranden see update

Comment: Yeah that looks normal and sane... I couldn't reproduce your issue. What platform and O.S. are you on? I assume you're using terminal Vim and not GVim correct?

Comment: What happens in the terminal if you run `cat` and then press the up arrow, to see what it outputs in a "raw" mode? Does it output `^[OA` as expected, or something else? I find it odd that your commented mapping is using a lowercase `o` there... Why will that fix the issue I wonder? You seem to be getting upppercase `O` in the output when it fails...

Comment: Do you reproduce this problem if you skip your normal vimrc? Start it with `vim -u NONE -N`, then try to add one of the mappings `:inoremap <up> <nop>` and see if you still reproduce the problem... If you don't, then it's quite possibly something else you have in your vimrc or plugins...

Comment: @filbranden: see updated answers. In particular, I could *not* reproduce the problem by running `vim -u NONE -N`. Which is a bit strange, though, because it _is_ reproducible if `vimrc` contains only the keybindings above. But yeah, it seems it is some plugin interfering then.

Comment: Using `vim -u NONE -N` means the system-wide `/etc/vim/vimrc` is not sourced... Anything suspicious there?

Comment: I do see something odd in that your terminal seems to be producing `^[[A` for `<Up>` but your Vim expects it to be `^[OA` instead... Are you using Gnome Terminal? Or which terminal emulator? Does it have settings that you think can be related to what the arrow keys do?

Comment: Nevermind that last part... I see that too, Up arrow produces `^[[A` in `cat` even though Vim has different settings for it... Does `:set term=ansi` solve your issue? (Though I don't think you'd want that set in your initialization files...) Really puzzling this one!

Comment: `/etc/vim/vimrc` looks ok (and I did not modify the contents, but will add them to the question)
Terminal is Gnome Terminal 3.32.1 (and I'm not aware of any special settings regarding arrow keys; I also did a test after removing `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`, same problem). (Also, I did not mention I was inside `tmux`, but the issue is the same also outside of `tmux`, in a normal shell.)

Comment: `:set term=ansi` is the one that causes `[C[C[C[C[D[D[D[D[D[C[C[A[B[D[C`

Comment: Is the `<Esc>` key itself remapped? Does `:imap <Esc>` return anything? In general output of `:imap` by itself, does anything else stand out? I got to reproduce your issue after `:inoremap <Esc> <nop>`.

Comment: Bingo! I had `esc` remapped too (to get used to `jk` instead :D). Indeed, if I remove that mapping, than the issue is gone. (It seems that this morning: 1. I left it in the minimal `vimrc`, but 2. forgot to paste it here somehow, I have no idea why.)
Will update the the beginning of the question accordingly.
(Still it is an interseting question, why remapping `esc` breaks the remapping of the arrow keys.)

Comment: Awesome! That also explains why the mapping on `<esc>oA` fixes it, since it uses `<esc>` as a prefix so doesn't trigger the `<nop>` mapping right away... I'll write you an answer shortly.

Comment: @filbranden The up arrow produces a different escape sequence in your `cat` test, because Vim switches to *application*, or *keypad transmit* mode by sending the `smkx` sequence when it starts up. See `:help raw-terminal-mode` and https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_arrows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is that the mapping for `<Esc>` is interfering with other mappings. Since most special keys generate sequences that start with an ESC character (which typically shows up as `^[`), the mapping is causing Vim to take that initial ESC from the first mapping, which is ignoring the `<Esc>`, then keeping the rest of the characters (`OA`) as a normal sequence to be inserted.

Vim can usually handle mappings that involve prefixes, by waiting for further characters or until a timeout happens. That's how Vim can usually detect between an unmapped `<Esc>` and a special key.

It's unclear why it's not doing so when you're remapping `<Esc>`... It possibly has something to do with Vim converting the sequence for the `<Up>` key into `<80>ku` internally (where `<80>` is ASCII character 0x80), which might make Vim no longer think it's a longer sequence starting with `<Esc>`...

One thing is that when you create a longer mapping that starts with `<Esc>`, such as the one for `<Esc>oA` that you had commented, that *will* trigger the behavior of waiting for a timeout before triggering the macro, so that fixes your other mappings by not triggering the `<Esc>` macro right away. Note, in particular, that `<Esc>oA` isn't even what the Up arrow generates (it generates an uppercase `O` instead of a lowercase one.) But *any* sequence starting with `<Esc>` would be enough to trigger this behavior.

For example, I'd suggest using this as a workaround to remap both `<Esc>` and special keys:

```
inoremap <Esc><nop> <nop>
```

That will never match anything (as you don't have a way to produce `<nop>` as a keystroke), but it will have the intended side effect of delaying the initial `<Esc>` mapping enough for sequences starting with `<Esc>` to translate into special keys and match those mappings instead.

(Make sure you add a nice comment to that mapping, so you'll later recall *why* it's needed!)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation: the suggested work-around fixes the issue indeed!